# How can I insert MySQL in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to insert MySQL into my bash script.
How can I insert the following lines into bash code?

This is how I would enter MySQL...

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

and use this MySQL code...

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON example.*
TO 'yourUser'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'yourUserPassword';
\q
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use bash to do this, simply use the `-e` flag:

```
mysql -uroot -p<password> -e"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON example.* TO 'yourUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourUserPassword'"
```

Notice that you might have to flush the privileges after running the above:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

From the documentation:

> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database

To do this from a bash script you create a `sh` file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uroot -p<password> -e"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON example.* TO 'yourUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourUserPassword'"
mysql -uroot -p<password> -e"FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
```

Don't forget that you must set execute permission on the file:

```
chmod +x <filename>.sh
```

Then you should be able to execute the script using:

```
./<filename>.sh
```